# Data Type error while training a GNN model

Tags: graph, neural-network, pytorch, tensor

I created a dataset with 500 graphs as follows:

```
data_list = []
ngraphs = 500
for i in range(ngraphs):
      num_nodes = randint(10,500)
      num_edges = randint(10,num_nodes*(num_nodes - 1))
      f1 = np.random.randint(10, size=(num_nodes))
      f2 = np.random.randint(10,20, size=(num_nodes))
      f3 = np.random.randint(20,30, size=(num_nodes))
      f_final = np.stack((f1,f2,f3), axis=1)
      capital = 2*f1 + f2 - f3
      f1_t = torch.from_numpy(f1)
      f2_t = torch.from_numpy(f2)
      f3_t =  torch.from_numpy(f3)   
      capital_t =  torch.from_numpy(capital)
      capital_t = capital_t.type(torch.FloatTensor)
      x = torch.from_numpy(f_final)
      x = x.type(torch.FloatTensor)
      #edge_index = torch.randint(low=0, high=num_nodes, size=(2, num_edges), dtype=torch.long)
      edge_index = torch.randint(low=0, high=num_nodes, size=(num_edges,2), dtype=torch.long)
      edge_attr  = torch.randint(low=0, high=50, size=(num_edges,1), dtype=torch.long)
      data = Data(x = x, edge_index = edge_index.t().contiguous(), y = capital_t, edge_attr=edge_attr )
      data_list.append(data)
```

I am trying to write a Graph Neural Network Model:

```
import torch
from tqdm import tqdm
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torch.nn import Linear, LayerNorm, ReLU
from torch_scatter import scatter
from torch_geometric.nn import GENConv, DeepGCNLayer
from torch_geometric.data import RandomNodeSampler
class DeeperGCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels, num_layers):
        super(DeeperGCN, self).__init__()

        self.node_encoder = Linear(data.x.size(-1), hidden_channels)
        self.edge_encoder = Linear(data.edge_attr.size(-1), hidden_channels)

        self.layers = torch.nn.ModuleList()
        for i in range(1, num_layers + 1):
            conv = GENConv(hidden_channels, hidden_channels, aggr='softmax',
                           t=1.0, learn_t=True, num_layers=2, norm='layer')
            norm = LayerNorm(hidden_channels, elementwise_affine=True)
            act = ReLU(inplace=True)

            layer = DeepGCNLayer(conv, norm, act, block='res+', dropout=0.5,
                                 ckpt_grad=i % 3)
            self.layers.append(layer)

        self.lin = Linear(hidden_channels, 1)

    def forward(self, x, edge_index, edge_attr):
        x = self.node_encoder(x)
        edge_attr = self.edge_encoder(edge_attr)

        x = self.layers[0].conv(x, edge_index, edge_attr)

        for layer in self.layers[1:]:
            x = layer(x, edge_index, edge_attr)

        x = self.layers[0].act(self.layers[0].norm(x))
        

        return self.lin(x)
```

I have a basic training function:

```
def train():
      model.train()
      optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.
      out = model(data.x, data.edge_index, data.edge_attr)  # Perform a single forward pass.
      loss = criterion(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])  # Compute the loss solely based on the training nodes.
      loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
      optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
      return loss

##Train the model
for epoch in range(1, 500):
    loss = train()
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}, Loss: {loss:.4f}')
```

When I run the above, I keep getting the following error:

> RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Long

I had tried to fix all data type issues when I made by dataset. So I am not sure what is happening. If anyone could help.

Comment: `edge_attr = self.edge_encoder(edge_attr)`, `edge_attr` is *long*, but should be *float*.

Comment: Thanks!. I changed it to: edge_attr  = torch.randint(low=0, high=50, size=(num_edges,1), dtype=torch.float). It still throws the error.

Comment: Where does it throw it exactly?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-3070587b8dda> in <module>()
      1 for epoch in range(1, 500):
----> 2     loss = train()
      3     print(f'Loss: {loss:.4f}')
5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in linear(input, weight, bias)
   1845     if has_torch_function_variadic(input, weight):
   1846         return handle_torch_function(linear, (input, weight), input, weight, bias=bias)
-> 1847     return torch._C._nn.linear(input, weight, bias)
RuntimeError: expected scalar type Float but found Long

Comment: Not sure if its clear, but on line 2, loss = train().